# simple command "find" not working

Tags: find

so I'm in the main folder for my web hosts, trying to find a file using `find`.  I couldn't find it - it was listed as no such file or directory - and I thought maybe it isn't anywhere.

However the following command doesn't work either:

```
find index.php
```

which is wrong cause there are a gazillion of them.  Why is find not working?  Is there a better command to use?

Comment: `find /some/dir -name index.php`

Comment: It is generally important to include any output or error message produced. In your case it would have been either `index.php` or ``find: `index.php': No such file or directory``  depending on whether or not there was an `index.php` in your current directory.

Comment: I think it would really help if you could provide some output when you type a command that is failing.

Comment: @Victor, I had a similar problem, FWIW even passing debug flags like `-D stat` to `find` produces no output if find works correctly, finding no matches, but in an unexpected way.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The syntax of `find` is not like what you have written, please read the manual page `man find` to get detailed idea.

For example if you want to find files named `index.php` on the current directory and all the sub directories under it, you can use:

```
find . -name index.php -type f
```

If you want to search for files having names say `findex.php`, `index.phpfoo`, `index.php` you need to use:

```
find . -name '*index.php*' -type f
```

`*` is a glob pattern meaning zero or more characters.

On the other hand if you want to look in the current directory only :

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -name '*index.php*' -type f
```

Comment: `find index.php` works on my debian jessie.

Comment: @OrtomalaLokni That only lists `index.php` in the current directory if present, it doesn't look in subdirectories.

Comment: yours is the most concise explanation and example combo.  Thanks

Comment: The man page for find (on my current Ubuntu install "find (GNU findutils) 4.7.0-git") says that putting the `-name` first will reduce resource usage as otherwise it checks every object to see if it is a file, then checks the name. So, minor modification `find . -name index.php -type f` to speed things up a little.

Comment: I needed the quotes '' and it worked

Answer (score 18):

I had the same problem using find from findutils 4.7.0-git. If I do `find . -maxdepth 12 -name '*' -type f` then despite having a million files in the below tree no files are returned except those in the current dir. The problem for me was that the dirs below were links, so I needed to do:

```
find -L . -maxdepth 12 -name '*' -type f
```

The `-L` ensures that any **links** are followed (used to be --follow but that was deprecated).

Comment: My `find` command was missing dirs that I knew existed and it turned out they were links. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Look into the manage of find. There are multiple usage. For example:
Find .| grep  "Index.php"
Or find .  -name Xyz.php